# Call integrated SignalR web Api service from MVC application from javascript

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-services, amazon-web-services, asp.net-web-api2, signalr

Use the following code in your Web Api

API Server Code :

```
[EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
      public class NotificationHub : Hub
            {
              public void Hello(string message)
                {
                    Clients.All.hello("This Massage via server : " + message);
                }
            }
```

Use following code for Call your signalR function from client side or view.

Client Code:

```
<script>
    $.connection.hub.url = "http://localhost:51929/signalr";

    $.connection.hub.start()
        .done(function () {

           $.connection.notificationHub.server.hello("Hi Rajesh!");
        })
        .fail(function () { alert('Error!'); });

    $.connection.notificationHub.client.hello = function (message) {
        $('#message').append(message);
    };
</script>`
```